# How to add labels, arrow, in `AxisHelper` and how to increase`linewidth`?

Tags: three.js

I am pretty new in `Threejs`. I want to achieve this output. Could anybody help me How to make changes like that in `AxisHelper`?
[image]

And I have done so far like this [image]

Comment: @2pha I edited my ques little bit. Please have a  look.                                   I have just added `AxisHelper` and  changed the color.

Comment: @Mhd Creativity is up to you, actually. As a hint, if you want an axis helper like on the given picture, you can create it, using one sphere, three arrow helpers and three sprites.

Comment: take a look at the source of https://threejs.org/editor/

Comment: @prisoner849 I liked your idea. It worked out  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your best approach here would be to create the desired model in a 3D modeling program like blender or maya. You can then export this as JSON data which you can pass into three.js. This is a much easier approach to get the axis helper look you want and it's also very easy to add text in those programs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you send me any link like that?